# How can I scale Y axis when changing dataset in this NVD3 multi bar chart?

Tags: javascript, json, nvd3.js

I'm using NVD3 to generate a multi-bar / stacked chart.  Here is a [live fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/tamak/45ob9u87).

I am taking an original array of data, transforming it into an nvd3 compatible structure, and maintaining arrays for both the 'current year' (2018) and 'all years'.   The button at top allows you to toggle between all years and current year.

I'm pleased with the resulting chart with one exception.  The scaling of the Y axis doesn't work if you perform the following steps:

1.) load the chart / fiddle

2.) click 'team 3' (orange) label at the top legend area a couple of times

3.) note the way the left side (Y axis) changes to scale to the resulting min / max

4.) now click 'Current Year' button at top (to only show a single year of data)

5.) again click 'team 3' (orange) label at the top legend area a couple of times... the Y axis does NOT scale at all now to decrease the max amount when 'team 3' is disabled.

When the current year / all years button is clicked, I'm running the following that I thought would force the chart to adapt fully to the new data set and automatically have its Y axis bounds set based on the data and legend items toggled:

```
data = convertedArray; // THE ALTERNATE ARRAY OF DATA
chart.forceY([uniqueDollarAmounts[0], // THE DISTINCT VALUES THAT GOVERN THE Y AXIS AMOUNTS (AND BOUNDS?)
uniqueDollarAmounts2[uniqueDollarAmounts.length-1]]);
d3.select('#NVD3Chart svg').datum(data).call(chart);
```

What do I need to do to have disabling 'team 3' decrease the Y axis max value to the 392,710.1  value that the next highest team has (team 7)?  I also have observed that when you return back to 'All Years' it doesn't work as it does initially (speaking of the scaling of the Y axis)... so I'm breaking something when I pivot to the 2nd data set apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `chart.forceY(..)` is actually the opposite of what you want, it ensures that the Y Axis will ***not*** scale when the displayed data is filtered. The call to `.datum(data)` handles changes in the axis and data based on `data`. In fact simply remove both of these instances and it will Y-Axis scaling will work.

```
$('#sort').click(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "All Years") {
      $(this).val("Current Year");
        data = convertedArray;
        //chart.forceY([uniqueDollarAmounts[0], uniqueDollarAmounts2[uniqueDollarAmounts.length-1]]);
        d3.select('#NVD3Chart svg').datum(data).call(chart);
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        getLowerTeamData()
      }
      else {
        $(this).val("All Years");
          data = convertedArray2;
          //chart.forceY([uniqueDollarAmounts2[0], uniqueDollarAmounts2[uniqueDollarAmounts2.length-1]]);
          d3.select('#NVD3Chart svg').datum(data).call(chart);
          nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
          getLowerTeamData()
        }
});
```

A note on a functionality you are mentioning:

> I also have observed that when you return back to 'All Years' it doesn't work as it does initially

This is because when the chart is first loaded `chart.forceY` was not used, as such the Y Axis will scale correctly. When you go back to 'All Years' it applies (*or rather tried to apply*)`chart.forceY` which wasn't happening initially causing this issue to appear.

This problem is actually due to `chart.forceY(..)` not working for your initial dataset from what appears to be a typo on your end. Take a look carefully at line 119:

```
chart.forceY([uniqueDollarAmounts[0], uniqueDollarAmounts2[uniqueDollarAmounts.length-1]]);
```

The `uniqueDollarAmounts2` should be `uniqueDollarAmounts`, so the value of `uniqueDollarAmounts2[uniqueDollarAmounts.length-1]` is `undefined`. This causes `.forceY` to not work as intended which is why it still appears to scale when you filter "*`Team3`*".

[*Here is a fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/45ob9u87/6/) showing `chart.forceY` on the initial chart and the typo correction. Notice that the Y-Axis does not change when the data is filtered in any cases. The minim value on the 2018 data is different so you will notice the lower value does indeed change from `0` and `6,641.8` as you would expect.

[*Here is a fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/45ob9u87/7/) where instances of `chart.forceY` are removed. Notice that the Y-Axis scale appropriately now.